# Flex text item renderer multiple row

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, text, itemrenderer

I'm building an item renderer in order to have a list of these.
In these item renderer there is a first part that is a text component that should have 2 rows of text and then truncate it, the second part is just a label.
I'm trying to find how to put the text component on two rows.
Can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Vgroup. Inside it place two TextArea components.
Place this inside HGroup alongside a label

```
<s:HGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
    <s:VGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10" gap="0">
        <s:TextArea id="row1_text" width="400" height="100"/>
        <s:TextArea id="row2_text" width="400" height="100"/>
    </s:VGroup>

    <s:Label id="myLabel"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get it automatically the text on the two rows?

Comment: You need to build your own custom component. [Here](http://www.forestandthetrees.com/2008/03/11/flex-multiline-button/) is a reference for multiline label. Try to adapt the same for your purpose.